# Firebase: Unable to read/write to database after enforcing app check

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

I am following all the steps accordingly as shown in [the app check documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider?authuser=0&hl=en).

- Initially I registered my web application in the official `Google reCAPTCHA v3` website and acquired my private and public key. After that, I registered my `private key` in the app check section.
- After that I added both `app check` library and `firebase` to my web-app:

---

**login.js**:

```
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app-check.js"
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, signInAnonymously } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-auth.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "key here",
  authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "project_id",
  storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender_id",
  databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com",
  appId: "app_id"
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();

signInAnonymously(auth).then(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
                provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider('reCAPTCHA v3 public key'),
                isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true
            });
            window.open("/index.html", "_self");
        }
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    alert(errorCode+": "+errorMessage);
});
```

---

**index.js**:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "key here",
  authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "project_id",
  storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender_id",
  databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com",
  appId: "app_id"
};
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.database().ref("ac/0/").set(null);


//some code here to populate the array which is to be pushed into my firebase db


for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var db_values = {
        "Current Date":arr[i][0],
        "EmpNo":arr[i][1],
        "Flag":arr[i][2],
        "Prev Date":arr[i][3],
        "Total charge":arr[i][4]
    };
    firebase.database().ref("ac/0/").push(db_values);
}
```

---

After logging in, no data is being pushed into my `realtime database`, whereas I keep getting the following warning in my console:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Missing appcheck token (https://project_name.firebaseio.com/)

If I go to the console, and `unenforce` app check, only then the data is pushed. Why is that? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Since you call `window.open("/index.html", "_self");` and then again `initializeApp` in `index.js`, I have a feeling you're opening a new window that doesn't have any knowledge about the App Check or Auth state that you did in login.js.

Comment: If I remove `initializeApp` from `index.js`, I get this error in console: `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app).`

Comment: Moreover your answer contradicts the answer that you gave in a previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71106556/20877444

Comment: My answer in that links actually is the exact same as the comment I left here: if you load two separate pages, you'll need to initialize all Firebase services you use in each of them.  Your second page doesn't initialize App Check

Comment: Is there a way to intialize app check and firebase once in the `login.js` page and then use them in other pages without having to reinitialize in every page?

Comment: No. The browser has no memory from one page to the next. If you don't want to reinitialize, consider building a [single-page application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA).